# Distance between point process realizations

Tags: stochastic-processes, distance, point-process

Is there a valid distance metric for measuring how similar are the realisations of two point processes? E.g. let's say we simulate two histories $ h_1, h_2 $ in the time interval $ [0, T] $ for two Poisson processes : how can we measure how similar these histories are? Keep in mind that in the general case $ h_1, h_2 $ have different length. Also, let's assume that we do not have access to the parameterisations of the stochastic processes generating the observations, but just to the histories.

Comment: Seems to me that the closest to the metric I'm looking for is KL divergence defined in a formulation similar to the one found in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08585.pdf

Comment: This paper proposes a Wasserstein-distance based method to compute similarity between two point process realisation under mild assumptions (e.g. same cardinality of events).
http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6917-wasserstein-learning-of-deep-generative-point-process-models.pdf